# Calculate Based on Age from Birthdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am writing small vaccination scheduler application using nodejs, express and mongodb,form Inputs is childName and birthDate.

Hepatitis is the vaccine that will be vaccinated 30 days after the birth of the child.

Pneumococcal is the vaccine that will be vaccinated 60 days after the birth of the child.

I would like to calculate the age of the child within the days and how many days there are left for the vaccination. Moreover, I will make it to show on table. how can i calculate age and vaccinations days?

input

```
childName   :
Michael Young

birthDate   :  01/10/2018



table

childName--------birthDate -----age--------Hepatitis-----Pneumococcal

Michael Young--01/10/2017--xxxdays----xxxdays-------xxxdays

Justin Bieber----02/11/2018--xxxdays-----xxxdays------xxxdays
```